# Convert React SPA to HTTP items

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I have a SPA web application, in REACTJS for investment consultation. However, I have to refactor it to make it possible to share its states by link, so that the user shares the link and by the link the selected items are shared. I want to know if you have a solution through some lib nodeJs or React that helps me solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: try using react-router to setup pages that link to the items, and render the specific item/items based on the url, it can either be full paths such as example.com/item1 or also can be combined with GET parameters, example.com/items?i=1 something like that, I suggest you to look into react routers. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom

Comment: Based on the selection I make on the site, I need to change the URL and based on the URL, send a request to the back end to render.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share react state with only an http link and there's no stateful backend, you don't have a lot of options other than keeping state data in the URL.  There is a useQueryParams hook would give you the basic tools you need for something like that

https://github.com/pbeshai/use-query-params

You can see some discussion of this technique below with an independent implementation

https://medium.com/swlh/using-react-hooks-to-sync-your-component-state-with-the-url-query-string-81ccdfcb174f

Comment: Based on the selection I make on the site, I need to change the URL and based on the URL, send a request to the back end to render.